# How can I pass device token from AppDelegate.swift to ViewController.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Running xcode 8 with swift 3

Below is my ViewController file

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testWebview: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("inside viewDidLoad ")
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        guard let deviceTokenString = appDelegate.deviceTokenString else {
            print("can not get device token string")
            return
        }


        let deviceid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        print("====== device id =======")
        print(deviceid)

        let testURL = URL(string: "http://www.test.com/user?device=ios&deviceid=" + deviceid + "&devicetoken=" + deviceTokenString)


        let testURLRequest = URLRequest(url: testURL!)
        print("before load request")
        print(testURL!)
        RJWebview.loadRequest(testURLRequest)
    }

}
```

Below is my AppDelegate file

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var deviceTokenString: String?



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: { granted, error in
            if granted {
                print("YES。")
            }
            else {
                print("NO!")
            }
        })

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        print("==== didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ====")
        print("===== deviceTokenString =====")
        print(deviceTokenString!)
    }

}
```

Below is my debug area message

```
YES。
inside viewDidLoad 
can not get device token string
==== didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ====
===== deviceTokenString =====
DF9AB59resrF68532C07ECB00627E4632F08F02975D5C4adsfsd2e810A5EB4
```

It seems like I can not get device token string from AppDelegate.swift.
How can I get that?

or can I get device token in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Comment: Why don't u just save the device token string to your userdefaults?

Comment: race condition problem,i guess

Comment: you trying to get device token before it assign to deviceTokenString in app delegate.

Comment: Yes, it seems like this is the problem. Any way to fixed it?

Comment: either broadcast local notification or completionClosure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is executed always **after** `viewDidLoad` of the viewController, that's the reason why the string is empty.

To solve the timing issue you could do

- In `AppDelegate` declare a weak property.

  ```
  weak var viewController : ViewController?
  ```
- In `ViewController` > `viewDidLoad` set the property. You don't need to `guard` `AppDelegate`. If it was not there the app wouldn't have launched.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      print("inside viewDidLoad ")
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
      appDelegate.viewController = self
  }
  ```
- In `ViewController` put the code to load the web request is an extra method.

  ```
  func loadRequest(for deviceTokenString : String)
  {
      let deviceid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
      print("====== device id =======")
      print(deviceid)
      let testURL = URL(string: "http://www.test.com/user?device=ios&deviceid=" + deviceid + "&devicetoken=" + deviceTokenString

      let testURLRequest = URLRequest(url: testURL!)
      print("before load request")
      print(testURL!)
      RJWebview.loadRequest(testURLRequest)
  }
  ```
- In `AppDelegate` > `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` call the method.

  ```
  viewController?.loadRequest(for: deviceTokenString!)
  ```

Comment: Well explained. But I've a doubt, ___if `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is executed always after `viewDidLoad` of the viewController___ then why the console prints this order: __YES。, inside viewDidLoad__? Instead it should be __inside viewDidLoad , YES。__! Right??

Comment: Now, this makes sense 